# How can I repeat the x label for each panel in facet_wrap in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My problem is simple: Instead of having a single axis label for the entire plot on `x` (`y` is optional; my label is `""`), I want to repeat it for each **panel** in `facet_wrap()` (even with multiple lines). What I mean is: the normal output is this (tryind to write as little unnecessary code as possible):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(vars(Species), scales = "free")
```

[image]
What I want is this (plus the panel names; because of how I "faked" the graph, they aren't there):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by making separate plots for each catgeory of your facteting variable and glueing them together via `cowplot` or `patchwork`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)

plot <- function(x) {
  iris %>% 
    filter(Species == x) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length))+
      geom_point()+
      facet_wrap(vars(Species), scales = "free")  
}

# Using cowplot
lapply(unique(iris$Species), plot) %>% 
  plot_grid(plotlist = ., nrow = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# Using patchwork
lapply(unique(iris$Species), plot) %>% 
  wrap_plots(nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that only works with facet_wrap(..., scales = "free"). You lose the ability to have a common scale between plots using patchwork.

Comment: @PabloCánovas. Yep. In case of the OP this was not desired. But this could be fixed by computing the data range on the whole dataframe, pass it as an additional argument to the plot function and set the limits of the scale in each plot accordingly.